# Tensorflow Serving of model with 3 versions present on disk but only latest is available

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I'm running tensorflow_model_server (version 1.8.0 installed using apt-get) with the --model_config_file option.

My config file is something along the lines of:

```
model_config_list: {
  config: {
    name: "MyModelName",
    base_path: "<path to model>/MyModelName"
    model_platform: "tensorflow"
  }
}
```

In the the MyModelName directory there are 3 versions of the model (directories 1, 2 and 3).

When I start the model server, I can see that version 3 is made available and I can access it via a serving client by not specifying the version (so the latest is assumed) or specifically asking for version 3.

If I try and specifically ask for version 2 of the model the request fails with an error message "Servable not found for request: Specific(MyModelName, 2)".

Is it possible through the tensorflow_model_server command line options or content of my model config file to have all versions of the model present on disk available to be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was trying to solve the same problem. If you see the [ModelConfig](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/config/model_server_config.proto#L19) definition, there is a field called [model_version_policy](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/config/model_server_config.proto#L48) of type [FileSystemStoragePathSourceConfig.ServableVersionPolicy](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.proto#L8). So ideally if you set this field in your config like so:

```
model_config_list: {
  config: {
    name: "MyModelName",
    base_path: "<path to model>/MyModelName"
    model_platform: "tensorflow",
    model_version_policy: {all: {}}
  }
}
```

then you should be able to change the version policy to load all available versions.

See [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/764) github issue for more info.

Comment: Your solution is just what I needed - I've struggled to find documentation on the format/contents of the model_config_file and to be honest even if I'd looked at the github source you referenced, I'd not have known how to translate that to the extra line in the file.

Comment: Is it possible to not use config list file but just pass this as argument to tensorflow_model_server? I have browsed through the possible argument this executable takes but couldn't see this yet.